# Ошибка с оператором "else"

Tags: pascal

Моя задача найти в последовательности сумму чисел кратных 6 и оканчивающихся на 4. Кол-во элементов в последовательности не известно, но их не может быть больше 1000. Если напечатал 0 - цикл прекращается.
Вот мой нерабочий код.

```
var sum, num : integer;

begin
  writeln('Ввод чисел последовательности'); 
  for var i:=1 to 1001 do 
  begin
    readln(num);
    if (num = 0) then //Ввод числа 0 останавливает ввод чисел последовательности
      break
    else //Если число не 0
      if (num / 6 = 0) and (num mod 10 = 4) then //Проверка достоверности основного условия
        sum := sum + num; //Если так, то добавляем это число к сумме
  end;
  writeln('Сумма:');
  writeln(sum)
end.
```

Я полностью уверен, что моя проблема в `else`. Как я ни крутил, то вылезала ошибка (Встречено "else", а ожидался оператор). Сейчас ошибки нет, но программа все равно работает неправильно:

```
Ввод чисел последовательности
24
981
54
0
Сумма:
0
```

Можно ли исправить ошибку с `else` и как нибудь улучшить цикл?

Answer (score 2):

Выражение `num / 6 = 0` может иметь только один вариант, когда оно будет выполняться - это `num=0`, но до этого даже не доходит.)
Используйте тоже mod, как в выражении рядом.

```
if (num mod 6 = 0) and (num mod 10 = 4) then
```

И еще у вас не задано начальное значение sum.

Comment: А ещё там `elsе` не нужен вообще, т.к. после `break` дальнейшая часть цикла всё равно выполнена не будет.